# Cheapest way to switch from Exodus wallet to something else

Tags: private-key-import

A few months back I moved my Bitcoins and Ether to Exodus.  I've now decided, as pretty as it may be, the high transaction charges and no way of changing them mean I want to switch wallets. There are other issues too, but this is the main one driving me away.

I tried using Jaxx to transfer the small amount of Ether, using the exported key from Exodus's developer menu.  However, this appears to have swept my Exodus address, rather than importing the address and private key into Jaxx.  It wasn't a complete sweep either - there is still balance in my Exodus Ether wallet.

What I am looking for is a way to just switch Bitcoin wallets from Exodus to something else, at minimum cost.

I believe I should be able to do that by *importing* private keys exported from Exodus into some other wallet, but my experience with Jaxx suggests that not all wallets support this. Jaxx support *sweeping* only.  [A discussion of difference between sweeping and importing on 99 coins](https://99bitcoins.com/know-more-private-key-import-vs-sweep-difference/).

Am I right in my thinking?  If I am, can you suggest good wallets that support what I want to do, and have clear documentation about how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exodus eventually answered this questions themselves, with a similar answer to that given by @McLeodX but specifically discussing import of BTC private keys rather than sweep or transfer.

In short, export BTC private keys from Exodus, import them into Bitcoin.info wallet, then use bitcoin.info to do future transactions with fees that can be adjusted.

I am sure there are other wallets for which this method will also work.

Answer (score 2):

I closed my Exodus account for the same reason. The worst case was with Bitcoin with a $200 transfer fee!  Of course it goes to the miners, but Exodus doesn't allow you to reduce it.  Exodus makes their money by taking a % on exchanges.

I found BitcoinCore the most economical for Bitcoin. You can set the transaction fee as low as you like. Since I am just sending it to myself (paper wallet, or friends) I don't need 6 confirmations in 1 hour.  If it takes a week, that's worth it to save $200.

The other advantage of running Bitcoin Core (Bitcoin.org) is that you are helping the network by storing and updating the 200 GB blockchain locally.  You can search the blockchain on your own computer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get a blockchain.info wallet and transfer all your btc there, and get a MEW(MyEtherWallet) and transfer all your Ether there.  100% free is about as cheap as it gets, and I’m not sure if a “pretty” wallet is important unless you plan on staring at your coins all day.

Comment: Are you saying the wallets are free, or that I can transfer my private keys into them without having to pay Exodus high transfer fees? (I don't believe that any parts of the fee go to Exodus, it's just how they ensure they are a fast wallet)

Comment: Yeah for sure, blockchain.info (for example) has the longest running and one of the more secure wallets anywhere, and they are free to setup, own and use (small fee for withdrawals, which is standard anywhere).  I don’t know what exodus is, but go an create a blockchain.info wallet, then transfer your coins there.  You don’t need private keys for that.

Comment: The point is Exodus is a wallet with high fees that can't be changed. I'm looking for a way to transfer the balance to another wallet without incurring those high fees.

Comment: How high can the fees to withdraw coins from one wallet to another possibly be?  If “high fees” are comparative to other wallets then you’re going to have to bite the bullet and pay fees no matter who you’re with, if they’re significantly more expensive then how are exodus still in business.  If you look at your situation logically, the only 2 ways to move your coin is a) withdraw to another wallet, b) convert to some other medium like other cryptos or fiat inside exodus (if you can) and then withdraw.  I’m not sure what magical third option you’re expecting people to conjure up, but that’s it

Comment: For small transactions (e.g. <$5), Exodus sets fees that are often higher than the transaction. Other wallets allow the fees to be set, balancing speed and cost. So what you are saying is private keys don't allow you to move balance between wallets without a bitcoin transaction taking place?

Comment: Other wallets don't have fees, or the fees are insanely small.  I get the feeling you're quite new to this, and my advice is don't get too wrapped up on fee structures of wallets, instead save your time and set up a free and extremely secure wallet at blockchain.info and transfer your coins there today and forget about exodus.

Answer (score 0):

Exodus allows in the setting now to change fees to slide from higher speed higher cost to lower speed lower cost.