# What happens if the Exodus company and servers shut down?

Tags: backup, exodus

I am reasonably confident about the security of my Exodus wallet, i.e. no one's going to steal my coins (not easily), however I can't get the following around my head...

What happens if Exodus and its servers cease to exist overnight or get closed down by the FBI or other government institutions? In this case, do we all lose access to our wallets or do we have anything by way of the 12 word key and user password that can enable us to import the wallet into another software/hardware wallet application?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheapest way to switch from Exodus wallet to something else](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60175/cheapest-way-to-switch-from-exodus-wallet-to-something-else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exodus allows you to backup your private keys ([look here](http://support.exodus.io/article/86-how-can-i-view-my-private-keys)). so if exodus will stop their service and you do not want to use exodus anymore (or maybe you can not) you can import your private keys in an other wallet and will not loose any funds.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering how this works in practice. Are you aware of any other wallet right now where I can upload the exported private keys, enter a password and be up and running?